# D3 axisBottom scale domain issue when resizing after transform

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a simple plot that is zoomable, pannable, and dynamically resizes with the window. In this case I only want it be to zoomable and pannable on the x axis. I'm using d3 v4.

The main issue I have run into is that the domain of the bottom axis will shift/slide when the page is being resized after the plot has been transformed. On resizing without having first transformed the plot, the bottom axis behaves as desired and maintains its domain, just "compressing" and "expanding" on resize.

To see the desired behavior, you can resize the plot without first transforming the plot by zooming or panning, and you'll see that the bottom axis maintains its domain.

To see the undesirable behavior, you can pan or zoom the plot and then resize the page. You will notice that the domain of the bottom axis will slide/shift.

I suspect there is something I'm doing wrong with setting my scales, however I am quite stuck.

The snippet below is a minimum working example of what I am working with:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", redraw);

let parentRect = $("#i3061007142472").parent()[0].getBoundingClientRect();
let pWidth = parentRect.width;
let pHeight = parentRect.height;

var margin = {
    'top': 10,
    'right': 30,
    'bottom': 30,
    'left': 60
  },
  width = pWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = pHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#i3061007142472")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height + 20);

var zoom = d3.zoom();
zoom.on("zoom", zoom_handler_dataplot);
d3.select("#i3061007142472").call(zoom);

var x_i3061007142472 = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date('0'), new Date('10')])
  .range([60, width]);

x_i3061007142472.type = "time";

var svg_gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "xAxis dataplot")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)

svg_gX.call(d3.axisBottom(x_i3061007142472).ticks(5));

var y_i3061007142472 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([height, 0]);
y_i3061007142472.type = "linear";

let vd_xaxis_i3061007142472 = x_i3061007142472.copy();
let vd_yaxis_i3061007142472 = y_i3061007142472.copy();

var svg_gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "yAxis dataplot")
  .style("padding-left", "50px")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 60 + ", 0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y_i3061007142472).ticks(5));

allow_pan_dir = "x";
domain = x_i3061007142472.domain();

function zoom_handler_dataplot() {
  if (allow_pan_dir != "none") {
    if (allow_pan_dir == "x" || allow_pan_dir == "both") {

      vd_xaxis_i3061007142472 = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x_i3061007142472);
      domain = vd_xaxis_i3061007142472.domain()
      svg_gX.call(d3.axisBottom(vd_xaxis_i3061007142472));

    } else {
      vd_xaxis_i3061007142472 = x_i3061007142472;
    }
    if (allow_pan_dir == "y" || allow_pan_dir == "both") {
      vd_yaxis_i3061007142472 = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y_i3061007142472);
      svg_gY.call(d3.axisLeft(vd_yaxis_i3061007142472));
    } else {
      vd_yaxis_i3061007142472 = y_i3061007142472;
    }
  }
}

function redraw() {
  console.warn("calling redraw");
  console.warn(allow_pan_dir);
  chartWidth = parseInt(d3.select(".dataplot_i3061007142472").style("width"));
  chartHeight = parseInt(d3.select(".dataplot_i3061007142472").style("height"));
  height = chartHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom + 20;

  x_i3061007142472.range([60, chartWidth]);
  y_i3061007142472.range([chartHeight - 30 - 10 + 20, 0]);

  if (allow_pan_dir == "x" || allow_pan_dir == "both") {

    vd_xaxis_i3061007142472 = d3.zoomTransform(d3.select("#i3061007142472").node()).rescaleX(x_i3061007142472);

    svg_gX.call(d3.axisBottom(vd_xaxis_i3061007142472));

  } else {
    vd_xaxis_i3061007142472 = x_i3061007142472;
  }

  if (allow_pan_dir == "y" || allow_pan_dir == "both") {
    vd_yaxis_i3061007142472 = d3.zoomTransform(d3.select("#i3061007142472").node()).rescaleY(y_i3061007142472);
    svg_gY.call(d3.axisLeft(vd_yaxis_i3061007142472));
  } else {
    vd_yaxis_i3061007142472 = y_i3061007142472;
  }

  let currTransform = d3.zoomTransform(d3.select('#i3061007142472').node());
  d3.select("#i3061007142472").call(zoom.transform, currTransform);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css ">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.0.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-il/oXcqETt5LGGmWWbOZLxrDgQQXlr7+ZI37ksA//3e9mxFloAOzlkF8SqtMOlWL6zTCk8hPYUQnreiQvT4elQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="my_plot" style="display: flex; flex: 1;">
    <svg id="i3061007142472" class="dataplot_i3061007142472 dataplot"></svg>
  </div>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried changing the domain on resize to match the transformed, tried using an intermediary scale, tried modifying the reference scale.